# Format GPS coordinates in text message as clickable link iOS/Android

Tags: android, ios, gps, sms

I have a script that sends a GPS location via text message to both iOS and Android users.  Is there a URL/prefix that can be used to tell mobile devices the text is GPS coordinates so it opens in the native mapping app?  48.238921,-84.015450

The only alternative I can think of is adding the coordinates to a google maps URL and if they have the Google Maps app, it would open and if not it would take them to the web version.

http://maps.google.com/maps?z=12&t=m&q=loc:38.9419+-78.3020

Would appreciate any suggestions.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

check out [geo URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geo_URI_scheme)

```
geo:38.9419,-78.3020
```

such link clicked on Android will prompt user in which app he want to open it and system will list all navigation-related apps. Google Maps for shure, but user may have some other. The downside is that web browser isn't a "map app", so it won't show on list, so on devices without any map-app (e.g. these without Google Play Services) such links are no-op

Comment: Appreciate the thoughts, I had also looked into this as it seems similar to using tel: before a phone number; however it does not appear to be supported by iOS.  I tested again today and my iPhone did not hyperlink it.

Comment: I'm very supprised that iOS doesn't support geo scheme, don't have any other idea...

Comment: I ended up just appending to this google maps URL to hyperlink right into google maps: 'google.com/maps/?q='